# What transition word should I use in this sentence?

Tags: word-choice

I am taking an SAT practice test. The question asks you to either keep the word, or replace it with another available option. The surrounding context of this question is:

> Assessments of the US job market typically focus
> on two main demographics: the employed and the
> unemployed. Often overlooked, **in fact**, is the
> category of underemployed workers, which has grown
> significantly since the 2008 recession.

The question as you to replace(or keep) the phrase in fact with one of these options.

- A) No Change
- B) However,
- C) Indeed,
- D) Moreover,

Can you guys tell me which you think the answer is and why? I can't figure it out, so any help would be good.

Comment: See if you can tell if you need a word of contrast or one that goes further in the same direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**"However" is the correct answer.**

The SAT is a standardized test, which means that there **can only be one correct answer.**

"In fact," "moreover," and "indeed" *all mean the same thing.*  **This means that they must be wrong.**

Since the test is *objective,* you will never have to choose the "better" answer out of two (or more) options.  Instead, three of them will be **completely wrong,** and one will be **completely right; *there is no in-between.***

**"However" is the only answer that *opposes* what has been previously written, whereas the other three simply *add* to it.**